# PHPExcel get font color doesn't work

Tags: fonts, colors, phpexcel

I'm trying to get cell's font color value, but it always returns black color.
I've tested it  with a few files in different formats(xls and xlsx).
Here is my code:

```
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify(self::PRODUCTS_FILE);
    $oExcelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $oExcelReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $oExcel = $oExcelReader->load(self::PRODUCTS_FILE);

    $worksheetsCollection = $oExcel->getAllSheets();

    $products = array();
    foreach($worksheetsCollection as $oWorksheet) /** @var \PHPExcel_Worksheet $oWorksheet */ {

        $rows = $oWorksheet->toArray();
        unset($rows[0]);
        if (!empty($rows)) {

            foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
                $color = $oWorksheet->getStyle('A' . ($key + 1))->getFont()->getColor()->getRGB();
                var_dump($color, 'A' . ($key + 1));
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong is

```
$oExcelReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
```

You're telling PHPExcel to read only the raw content of the cells, and **not** to read any style information such as font colour, etc.

This means that the font colour isn't being read from the file at all, so any request to get the colour used will return only the default colour for the spreadsheet, which is black

If you want colour information, ***don't*** tell PHPExcel to retrieve only the spreadsheet data